# Invariant factor decomposition for a $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Find the invariant factor decomposition of ${\rm Hom}_\mathbb{Z}( \mathbb{Z}/30 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z},  \mathbb{Z}/15 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})$

I know how to find invariant factor decomposition for $\mathbb{Z}/30 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/15 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

But I am confused how to find the decomposition of the set of homomorphism between those two. What I thought is since there are only finitely may such homomorphisms, so can first find all the homomorphisms then find decomposition. But I don't know how to do that exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is good but you can drastically reduce the computation necessary.
For this convince yourself of the following facts:

$$
{\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(A\times B,C)\cong{\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(A,C)\times{\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(B,C)\\
{\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(A,B\times C)\cong {\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(A,B)\times {\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(A,C)
$$

The remaining homomorphism sets are very easy to compute by hand. This will give you a decomposition of your original homomorphism group as direct product of quotients of $\mathbb Z$. From here you can get the desired invariant factor decomposition.

Comment: Thanks, just I am actually confused about how to find decomposition of $Hom_\mathbb{Z}( A, C)$, is it decomposition of A$\times$C?

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll No. It might be the case that it is $A\otimes_\mathbb Z B$ but don't take my word for it. It should be that hard to compute ${\rm Hom}_\mathbb Z(A,B)$ with both $A$ and $B$ just quotients of $\mathbb Z$ as any homomorphism is uniquely determined by the image of a generator.